# how to read certain row and column from list

Tags: r

```
setwd("C:\\Users\\tom24\\Desktop\\DATA TREND\\ONEMONTH")

fileNames = list.files(pattern="xlsx")
for(i in 1:length(fileNames)){
  data = read_excel(path=fileNames[i], sheet=1, col_names=FALSE)
  assign(x=fileNames[i], value=data)}

KING <- lapply(paste("C:\\Users\\tom24\\Desktop\\DATA TREND\\ONEMONTH\\",sep="",print(fileNames)),read_excel)

EXAMPLE<-KING[c(1:2500),c(1,4)]
```

I would like to read certain rows and columns which is [c(1:2500),c(1,4)] from all the files in the folder. However, it says incorrect number of dimensions.

Comment: i want to make a dataframe from those rows and columns. Thanks

Comment: Your problem was that you were trying to index the list with the columns of the data frames. The list contains data frames with 2500 rows, but the list itself has a single dimension and length equal to the length of fileNames.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this in one `lapply` call :

```
fileNames = list.files('path/to/folder/', pattern="\\.xlsx", full.names = TRUE)

lapply(fileNames, function(x) {
  readxl::read_excel(x, col_names=FALSE)[1:2500, 1:4]
}) -> result

result
```